# Share folders from Guest OS to Windows Host OS Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shared folder virtualization in Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81757/shared-folder-virtualization-in-ubuntu-11-10)

So most articles are focused on the Virtualbox forcing a folder into the Guest OS.  I want to do the opposite, share a folder out of to the host OS.  I tried doing the automagic share folder via nautilus menu and that didn't work.  The computer also fails to show up in the Host OS's list of computers in the network.

It works fine with other full Linux OS's.