# How to add users to vboxusers to enable USB usage

Tags: virtualbox, users, groups

I want to use my flashdrive in Windows XP, which I am currently running in Virtualbox, but when I open up the settings to enable usb usage, I get an error:

```
Failed to access the USB subsystem.
VirtualBox is not currently allowed to access USB devices. 
You can change this by adding your user to the 'vboxusers' group. 
Please see the user manual for a more detailed explanation


Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x00004005)
Component: 
Host
Interface: 
IHost {30678943-32df-4830-b413-931b25ac86a0}
Callee: 
IMachine {22781af3-1c96-4126-9edf-67a020e0e858}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access a shared folder in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox)

Comment: @wesinat0r That's about shared folders, and this is about directly accessing USB devices (which VirtualBox supports).

Answer (score 90):

In your host, run this command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER
```

Now perform a logout (always required after add current user to a group).

After login, check that you are in the `vboxusers` group with this command, make sure that `vboxusers` is in the shown list:

```
groups $USER
```

Comment: i am getting error: usermod: group 'vboxusers' does not exist

Comment: ```adduser: The group `vboxusers' does not exist.```  Now what?

Comment: Oh wait, this is something you run in the host OS, not the guest OS?

Comment: Actually, for Linux guests + hosts (not exactly the question but helpful), you need to do BOTH `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers "$USER"` on the **host** AND `sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf "$USER"` on the **guest** after extension pack install and then **reboot** the guest.

Comment: Only logout doesn't work. I have to reboot to make it work.

Answer (score 19):

This works for me and my problem with VirtualBox was solved

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf "$USER"
```

Comment: i am getting error: `usermod: group 'vboxsf' does not exist`

Comment: I don't know why installing VirtualBox does not add that group for you, maybe will it be good idea to add group manually first

Answer (score 8):

1. Add the user as suggested by other answer using usermod command.
2. Run the command `id`.  You should see `vboxusers` in the list.
3. If you don't see that, you may restart your computer and try `id` again.

When you get vboxusers listed as a result of running `id`, you're good to use USB with virtual box.

Comment: Instead of restarting, simply logging off and on again also works.

Answer (score 7):

1. In a terminal run:

   ```
   sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
   ```
2. Reboot **all systems**.

Answer (score 3):

```
id <username>
```

That will give you

```
uid=1000([username]) gid=1000([username]) groups=1000([username]),10(wheel),18(dialout),497(plugdev)
```

if vboxusers is missing in that then add it

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers [username]
```

This should resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Would like to mentionn for those who no solution work like me, ensure you are part of the group vboxusers, if it does not exist, addgroup vboxusers.... after, delete in the host usb settings all the usb filters (devices) you have...   reboot the guest     In the host, use empty filters to recreate manually your devices, put any name just copy the two following fields from the original filter still available, restart your virtual guest.... voila,   your devices are there ...    its the only way i found to force them  out of at least ten other solutions.. Enjoy