# Virtualbox USB Access

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtualization, windows-10

I am trying to allow my Windows 10 virtual machine access to my USB devices. This seems pretty straightforward, according to [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31726/mount-usb-devices-in-virtualbox-with-ubuntu/). I need to install the Guest additions which I did by clicking Devices in the Virtual machine > Insert guest additions cd > and then double clicking it in file explorer and going through the install wizard.

However, When I go to the USB settings and try and check "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" I get an error message

> Invalid settings detected
>
> USB Page:
>
> USB 2.0 is currently enabled for this virtual machine. However this requires the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack to be installed. Please install the Extension Pack from the VirtualBox download site or disable USB 2.0 to be able to start the machine.

Easy enough, I head on over to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3 and download the 4.3.36 extension pack. Then install it with: `sudo vboxmanage extpack install --replace ~/Downloads/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.36-105129.vbox-extpack` this says it installs successfully. I restart VirtualBox andddd... I still have the error about invalid settings detected and am unable to use a USB within windows.

I've done quite a bit of searching on this issue and pretty much everything says I need to either install the guest additions cd or install the extension pack, both of which have already been done.

Comment: Are you sure this version of the extension pack is correct for your version of VirtualBox? In particular, how did you install VirtualBox?

Comment: Never had an issue with this. Here's how I always do that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Comment: @fkraiem yes I'm sure I checked I was using VirtualBox 4.3.36 before downloading. I installed it through the official repositories

Comment: You need to join vbox users group: http://askubuntu.com/questions/377778/how-to-add-users-to-vboxusers

Comment: @PabloBianchi: That doesn't address the dysfunctional extension pack installation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join vbox users group in order to use physical USB devices in VirtualBox with Ubuntu.

The method is shown in this post: [How to add users to vboxusers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377778/how-to-add-users-to-vboxusers)

The How-to Geek page you refer to looks quite old.