# Add user to virtual box to fix Vm USB problem

Tags: users

Could someone explain why does the user needs to be added to the virtual box, please/

[How to add users to vboxusers to enable USB usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377778/how-to-add-users-to-vboxusers-to-enable-usb-usage)

The problem is described and solved in the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a USB storage device is connected, it is usually mounted in `/mount/{username}` with access permissions being granted to `{username}`. For example, when I plug a USB stick into my notebook, I can see this in the appropriate `/media` directory:

```
drwxr-x---+ 3 root  root  4096  3月  3 10:00  ./
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096  9月 23  2019  ../
dr-xr-xr-x  1 jason jason 2048  8月  1  2020 'Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS amd64'/
```

VirtualBox VMs operate under the `vboxuser` group permissions. So, just like you cannot access or modify `root`-owned files without `sudo`, VirtualBox cannot access `{username}`-owned files without permission. By adding `{username}` to the `vboxuser` group, VirtualBox will have a degree of access to the USB-mounted storage locations.