# Help detecting a USB plotter device to pass through on VirtualBox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, devices

I am using Ubuntu, but have a USB plotter I need to use occasionally that works best with software that only runs in Windows.  I thought a good solution would be to use Windows as a guest in VirtualBox, but I cannot get the plotter to be detected by the software in Windows.
Much of the help I've found about this relates to storage devices that would 'mount' within Ubuntu, but since this is a plotter I expect it is handled differently and I don't know how to proceed.

Currently I have a USB filter with blank fields set in VirtualBox.

`lsusb` does not list this device.

`VBoxManage list usbhost` also does not list this device.

The device details do appear with `udevadm` attribute walk, and also `dmesg`.

So it seems that at lease on some very low level this is being recognized?  Is there a way I can force this device to be recognized or handled at a higher level so that VirtualBox can pass it through?

Comment: If you don't get the hostbus, hostaddr from lsusb, maybe using the vendorid, productid would work -- are those in the outputs you have? I can use either way with kvm, don't know much about virtualbox

Comment: @ubfan1 I do have the vendor id and product id from `dmesg`.  I can add this to the filters list in VirtualBox and the USB connection still is not found.

Comment: @ubfan1 It was basically a permissions issue, I needed to be added to the `vboxusers` group in order to have access to any usb devices at all.

Comment: You may answer your own question, and accept it after a bit, helping others and gaining some reputation in the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see the device via lsusb when Virtualbox if off, you won't be able to pass it through Virtualbox. Are you positive it's not showing up in lsusb, perhaps under a generic name?

Answer (score 0):

@Mr. T Evertyhing works as expected after adding my profile to the `vboxusers` group.  This device still does not show up under `lsusb` but it is available to VirtualBox and usable in the guest.

This post was helpful - [How to add users to vboxusers to enable USB usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377778/how-to-add-users-to-vboxusers-to-enable-usb-usage)