# Share with Mac from Vbox Ubuntu help

Tags: virtualbox, samba

Complete noob... I installed VirtualBox and Guest additions for Ubuntu, managed to set up a 'shared folder' in virtualbox devices but my question is. Now that I have set up the Share on my Mac (made it public/all) how do I now find this folder using Ubuntu?

Ideally, I want the 'shared folder' to go on my desktop in Ubuntu.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

To have a Virtualbox shared folder on the Ubuntu guest's desktop we will have to create a shared folder to then mount it. See these related questions:

- [Error mounting VirtualBox shared folders in an Ubuntu guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest)
- [How to mount a VirtualBox shared folder at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup)
- [How to access a shared folder in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-shared-folder-in-virtual-box)

If this was successful we need to give our Ubuntu user privileges to read (or write) these shared folders by granting them access to the group `vboxsf`. Run this command from a terminal in the guest:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf <username>
```

Both, shared folders auto-mounting to `/media/<username>/sf_<sharename>`, and user membership in the group `vboxsf` need a **reboot** of the guest.

We can then simply drag and drop the shared folder to the guest's desktop for easy access:

[image]

To access from guest applications we give the mountpoint (i.e. the path) to the share (when auto-mounted in `/media/<username>/sf_<sharename>`) in the file-selector.