# How to access the shared folder in Virtual Box?

Tags: server, virtualbox, virtualization, shared-folders

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Server (guest machine) on VirtualBox having Windows 7 as host machine.

I make a "Server12.04" named folder on my Host machine desktop & shared the same in Virtual Box (ticked the auto-mount option). How can i access the shared folder in the guest machine (which 
is Ubuntu server 12.04).

I got one refrence answer from [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-shared-folder-in-virtual-box) but this was not helpfull. Whenever i tried to share the folder 
i got the following error :-

The program 'VmBoxManage'  is currently not installed. You can install it by typing `apt-get install virtualbox`.  Means why to install VirtualBox inside the VirtualBox ??

Please help me out . Thanks in advance !!

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup and http://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest - VboxManage is installed on the host, not the guest,

Answer (score 0):

On your host OS, you create the shared folder by running

```
VBoxManage sharedfolder add "VM name" --name "sharename" --hostpath "C:\test"
```

On your guest system, you have to run

```
mkdir /home/<user>/vboxshare
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 share /home/<user>/vboxshare
```

VBoxManage can change the settings of a VirtualBox, but if you already have this share created, there's no need to run this command.

Comment: @davidbaumaan i have windows 7 as my host machine & having "share" named folder on my desktop which i want to share with my guest OS which is Ubuntu Server 12.04 (on VirtualBox) ?? you got me

Comment: Did it work? OF course, you have to adjust the command according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

On Ubuntu Server, without guest additions, manually mount the shared folder on the guest, e.g.:

```
mkdir /mnt/sharedfolder
sudo mount -t vboxsf FolderNameInVBoxSettings /mnt/sharedfolder
```

If the above works fine, add a corresponding entry in `/etc/fstab` to make it permanent.

**Detailed Intructions**

Let me share what has worked for me in two different setups, an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop and an Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Server on a Windows 10 host. I will use an example username `sun`. The first step is common, and is done via the VirtualBox UI (I have 6.1.26 at the time of posting), by selecting the target VM and going to *Settings > Shared Folders* and clicking the "Add shared folder" button:

[image: shared folder settings]

On the dialog box, I entered the Windows source path in "Folder Path", an arbitrary name for the shared folder under "Folder Name", and the "Mount Point" which is a valid path of my choosing, on the guest. Note that "somename" should be an empty directory:

[image: add shared folder details]

**For Ubuntu Desktop**

For a desktop, I also ticked the "Auto-mount" option above. Assuming that [guest additions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/guestadd-install.html) have already been installed, and that the `somename` directory exists, then that's all there is to it. The shared folder will be visible, even on reboot.

To avoid having to use `sudo` every time to access the shared folder, I did [one more thing](https://askubuntu.com/a/818844/628938):

```
sudo adduser sun vboxsf
```

**For Ubuntu Server**

For the server, without guest additions installed, I took note of the *ArbitraryName* above, because I will need to use the same name for the mount command on the Linux guest:

```
mkdir /home/sun/somename
sudo mount -t vboxsf ArbitraryName /home/sun/somename
```

I check that I can see the files:

```
cd /home/sun/somename
ls
```

Yes, the Windows files are there! But this mount will be lost on reboot, so I make it permanent by adding an entry to `/etc/fstab`:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/fstab

# My VirtualBox shared folder entry in /etc/fstab
ArbitraryName    /home/sun/somename   vboxsf   defaults  0   0
```

Again, `ArbitraryName` must be the same one specified in VirtualBox settings, i.e. the same one we used in the previous `mount` test command. Now I can reboot the machine and after login, I can do `ls /home/sun/somename` to see my Windows shared folder files! As a bonus, I didn't like the green highlight on the shared folder directories, so I added the following to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'ow=1;34:';
```

The above gets rid of that highlighting but still keeps the other colors, such as blue for directories. Hope this is helpful!