# VirtualBox shared folders are owned by root in Lubuntu guest

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, lubuntu

My Setup is as follows -

Host: Ubuntu Server 14.04
Guest: Lubuntu Desktop 15.10

I have shared dirs on host to guest with automount option, and the directories show up in Guest OS's just fine - /media/sf_sharename

Also, the user of guest is added to vboxsf group.

The problem is that all the shared dir and its contents are owned by root. I have tried chown -R, but it finishes without reporting error wihtin guest but the ownership does not change.

I have another setup where guest is ubuntu desktop 15.10, and I did not face this problem there.

I need rw access on those shared dirs. How to fix this?

Comment: What is the result of `grep vboxsf /etc/group` on the Guest system?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

On Ubuntu Server **host** execute these commands :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /path-to-shared-folder/shared-folder

sudo chown -R user1:user1 /path-to-shared-folder/shared-folder
```

On Lubuntu Desktop **guest** execute this command :

```
sudo usermod -G vboxsf -a user2
```

Restart the guest system for changes taking effect.

Note : `user1` = your **host user** name  | `user2` = your **guest user** name

Comment: To add a user to an existing group, you can also simply use `sudo adduser USERNAME GROUPNAME` instead of the described `usermod` command.

Comment: Does the $USER need to be a member of the group `vboxsf` on the Host system? My understanding was that this is only necessary on the Guest system...

Comment: @andrew.46 : Thank you for your comment ! Of course you have to add the user to the vboxsf group in the guest ... I thought that this a known fact, but I updated the answer to make it more clear - Thanks again ! :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Thanks for your answer. I think changing the permission on the host fixed it. I already had the guest user in vboxsf group.

Comment: why should I make the files accessible to all users on the host system with 777 just to have access in the virtual box? It seems much more to me, that something should be changed with the mounting in the guest system

Comment: The answer below `sudo mount -t vboxsf folder share -o uid=1000,gid=1000` works without changing permission of host

Comment: only second command required in my case

Answer (score 19):

No need to change main group of user - add user into group is sufficient.

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxsf
```

After the command do a restart or logout and login.

Comment: not enough as `mount -t` can only be done by root and you need it for vboxsf

Comment: Except that in some setups, `mount -t` is no longer needed, since the guest additions already do the mounting. In my case, this was all I had to do to get it working flawlessly, no need to change mount commands or folder permissions.

Comment: For me, a restart was needed after `adduser`, other than that the solution worked like a charm.

Comment: Why would adding my user to the vboxsf group do anything when the shared folder is owned by root? I did try it anyway and restarted, doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 13):

It is not necessary to change the permissions on the host system, just easily mount the shared folder for the normal user:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf folder share -o uid=1000,gid=1000
```

`1000` is the default ID of the default user. This can be checked by `id username`

Comment: works for me, thanks, my host is Mac, client os is CentOS 6.3

Comment: worked perfectly for me

Comment: In Virtualbox 6.1 with Ubuntu running as a guest, mounting the share will only provide read-only access.

Comment: When I added the share into VirtualBox 6.1, I made sure "Read only" was unchecked. I'm able to write just fine.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubunut 18.04 (and I thin same for 14) two question, because with proposals solutions, is not fine on too many scenarios such nginx and others.

1. Add user to group vboxsf
2. Add mount in /etc/fstab
3. Verify that user has 1000 for uid and gid using `id $USER`

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxsf $USER
```

/etc/fstab

```
shared_named_in_virtual_box /home/user/point_mount_name vboxsf defaults,dmode=755,fmode=644,gid=1000,uid=1000 0 0
```

After reboot, if you put correct values, you have a shared mount on  /home/user/point_mount_name with correct values, for chmod dirs and files, and chowned by your user.