# virtualbox shared folder is owned by root and not writable

Tags: permissions, mount, virtualbox, xubuntu

I have a shared folder between Xubuntu 16.04 (host) and Xubuntu 17.10 (guest). I have given write permission via virtualbox, but still I don't have permissions to edit the files on the guest system.

That is, because the folder is mounted to the guest system by

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf folder share
```

In the host system the `folder` is owned by the normal user and writable. But when mounted in guest, its owned by `root` and not writable for `others`. And when I try to change it via `sudo chmod` or `sudo chown` there is no effect.

In [another Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747974/virtualbox-shared-folders-are-owned-by-root-in-lubuntu-guest) it was answered, that you should give `chmod 777` to all files on the host system. But thats not something I want to do because I don't see why this should be necessary to do. Giving all permissions to all users on my host system cant be the best way.

I already added my guest user to the `vboxsf` group but that didn't change anything. I guess, I would need to mount the shared folder somehow not by root.

Comment: If the folder is owned by root in the host then you own user (at the host) cannot write to it either. How would the VM do it then?

Comment: Ownership alone does not determine who can write to it. What are the group and permissions? Typically, the permissions are `775` and the group is `vboxsf`, to which you add any user who needs write access.

Comment: @MichaelBay : on the host the files are owned by the normal user, not by root. Just when mounted on the guest system they are owned by root

Comment: And using guest additions won't help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is easy, just mount the shared folder for the standard user:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf folder share -o uid=1000,gid=1000
```

`1000` is the default ID of the default user. This can be checked by `id username`

Comment: That only works if `1000` is the only use that needs write access, so it's not ideal.

Comment: why? whats the problem? That way its still 775 and owned by the guest user.  Ok, when I would need files that would need to be edited and read by other (system) users it would be more complicated, but thats not the case here.