# Can't mount shared folder in VirtualBox

Tags: mount, virtualbox, shared-folders

I needed to share a folder between Ubuntu 16.04 guest and Windows host in VirtualBox.

However, the terminal shows the following output:

```
$ sudo mount -t vboxsf Ubuntu WinLinShare
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such file or directory
```

I have already re-installed GA three times.
I have checked and both the folders exist.
Any help please?

Comment: How did you try to set up the shared folder on both host and guest

Comment: Is that really a share named `olaf` that you want to mount to a directory `/Shared` you had previously created on the guest? Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest, https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox or https://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup