# how do i set up a virtual box shared folder in an Ubuntu 18.04 VM on a windows 10 host?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, virtualization, windows-10, shared-folders

i added a folder to the machine in VirtualBox, but from inside Ubuntu i can't get to the shared folder.

host: windows 10
guest: ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did you see these posts: https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox and https://askubuntu.com/questions/252853/how-to-mount-a-virtualbox-shared-folder-at-startup or https://askubuntu.com/questions/30396/error-mounting-virtualbox-shared-folders-in-an-ubuntu-guest ? If you have any issues with the steps outlined there please [edit] your question and tell us so. Thank you.

Comment: they were too far out of date, but i did find a recent tutorial for ubuntu 16.04 that worked with 18.04 https://gist.github.com/estorgio/1d679f962e8209f8a9232f7593683265

Comment: Actually, I try to keep my posts up to date - they should still work, because procedures haven't changed. If not **please shout** - only then we will be able to stay up to date. It is also where we are much better than forums, or blogs, or other static content in the Internet ;)

Comment: Thanks, the steps mentioned in the github hosted tutorial worked.

Comment: I am using virtualbox 6 and Ubuntu 18.04. Every guide I have found so far is out of date. I tried to follow along and ignore the subtle differences but nothing worked so far. If anyone knows of an updated guide it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First I added my username to vboxsf
(sudo adduser USER_NAME vboxsf)
And then I still had to install this package to see the shared folder => 
virtualbox-guest-utils