# How to access a Windows 10 shared folder using virtualbox

Tags: mount, virtualbox, automount, shared-folders

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. I want to try it as my development environment, since it will be cleaner than my home PC which is filled with games and kid's homeworks. I tried different Linux distros and decide that Ubuntu was the best in terms of speed/easyness of use. I liked Manjaro interfase more, but find quite difficult to use.

So, I want to have a folder in the host (**Windows 10**) which will be shared to the guest (**Ubuntu 18.10**), I'm using VirtualBox 5.2.22

I have follow the steps in this question: [How to access a shared folder in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox) but doesn't work.

I have also follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxL414FRccQ but doesn't work either.

This is what I have done:

- With the guest OS closed, I go to the VirtualBox GUI, select config/shared folders
- I choose the path, and I give it a name, I also click automount

[image]

- I start the VM, according to both articles, I should have the shared folder, in the Media folder, but it doesn't:

[image]

- If I list the `/etc/group` I see a `vboxusers` but not a `vboxsf` which is the one I should add my user to use the shared folder

Maybe there's a new procedure?

Comment: Yes, your username has to be in the vboxsf group for this to work. Also... I hope that you're NOT trying to access your Windows C: drive this way... but rather, a common shared NTFS partition/drive.

Comment: I think the proble was related to the Guest Additions,  created a new VM, reinstalled everything from zero, and this time it worked fine. I really don't know what I did wrong in the first place