# How do I share files between a VirtualBox Windows 95 Guest and Ubuntu 18.04 Host?

Tags: virtualbox, windows, file-sharing, shared-folders, virtualbox-networking

I tried using the "Guest Additions CD Image" provided by VirtualBox, but it doesn't run on this old version of Windows. :(  Not sure what to do. I then thought I could connect to the internet by using Windows 95's Internet Explorer and just email some file back and forth or use Google Drive or something, but I can't seem to connect the Windows 95 Guest to the internet either. It's expecting a modem or something.

Not sure what to do here.

Related Question that doesn't apply in my case since it's expecting a Windows 10 Host: https://superuser.com/questions/1003657/how-to-transfer-file-from-windows95-in-vmware-to-host-os

**IMPORTANT:** NOT A DUPLICATE OF [How to access a shared folder in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox), because that question is specific to more modern versions of Windows, such as Windows 7, and every single answer there relies on installing the "Guest Additions" package from VirtualBox onto the Windows Guest, which I've already stated *does not run on Windows 95* (as that's the first thing I tried since I'm familiar with Guest Additions).

Comment: You will need to install the standard NE2000 network adapter for anything network-related, yes.  We didn't have network adapters as standard in 1995.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 95 has SMBv1 file sharing, so:

1. Enable a private "host" network adapter on VirtualBox.
2. Power down Windows 95 and add a new or change an existing network adapter on your guest.  (From memory, Windows 95c had an NE2000 network driver, but Google an NE2000 adapter and follow my other answer if this isn't in your version.)
3. Power up your Windows 95 guest and install Windows File Sharing.
4. Enable/install `samba` on your host and create a share.
5. Edit the samba config to enable SMBv1, while being aware to make it listen only on the private "host-only" VirtualBox network.

Then you should be able to see your host in the "Browse" section of the Windows 95 guest network.

The reason you have to limit this to a private network is because SMBv1 is vulnerable to a ransomware attack which, while not affecting your Linux box, may offer an opportunity for other Windows machines on your network.

Answer (score 1):

A cludgier but nonetheless reliable solution is to:

1. Stop the Windows 95 Guest
2. Mount the Virtual Disk Image into the host OS.
3. Copy the files.
4. Unmount the Virtual Disk Image.
5. Start the Guest again.