# How can I change the owner of VirtualBox shared folders on Ubuntu 18.04 guest VM?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, mount, virtualbox, nginx

I am using a VM with Ubuntu 18.04 with GUI, and I am working on a Wordpress project with Nginx. I installed VBox guest additions, but I cannot change the owner of the shared folder, which I have set to auto mount in the /opt folder; the path to the shared folder is /opt/myfolder/THISFOLDER. I want to edit contents (files) inside THISFOLDER. I have tried the command `sudo chmod -aG vboxsf myusername` and rebooted to no avail. When I do `sudo chown -R myusername /opt/myfolder`, it also doesn't do anything. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this link help? https://www.howtogeek.com/438435/how-to-use-the-chown-command-on-linux/

Comment: @Graham no it does not. I have tried what's in the OP.

Comment: VBox host folder mounts don't exactly 'share' chmod permissions properly with the host, as the VM will consider it 'remote fileshare storage'.  You would have to alter the mount options for how you mounted the folder in the system to match the user you *want* ot to match at mount option time, as yuo cna't chown/chmod a VBox Shared Folder in a way that works right  (Same behavior applies to VMware shared folders too)

Comment: @ThomasWard how would I alter the mount options? I've already used the VBox shared folder settings to mount with Full access and Auto Mount. I installed via the built in option in "Devices." I'm on a Mac

Comment: How is it mounted inside the guest?  What command did you run to mount it inside the guest OS?  If you used the vbox automatic mounting it will use its user that is running the tools - root and superuser - which is why you get permissions issues

Comment: @ThomasWard I used this method: https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/. Do I need to uninstall it and redo it?

Comment: No, it's not an issue with the installed guest additions.  Using the 'automount' function is going to mount it differently than you need.  I'll have to dig deeper when I get a chance to see if we can 'reset' this to use a different mount user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98740/discussion-between-avig-and-thomas-ward).

Answer (score 2):

In your specific scenario, simply trying to change folder owner won't work. This is what has worked for me:

1. Create a shared folder `SHARED` (Host-side), from a local (Guest-side) path `/folder/path/`, give it full access and uncheck `automount` option in VirtualBox
2. Run `sudo usermod -aG vboxsf yourusername` on the Guest
3. Take note of your **userid**; run `cat /etc/passwd|grep yourusername` from the Guest to find it (it usually is 1000)
4. Edit `/etc/fstab` to add mount point to it: `SHARED /folder/path/ vboxsf defaults,dmode=755,fmode=644,gid=1000,uid=1000 0 0` on the Guest, replacing `gid` and `uid` with previous **userid**
5. Reboot the Guest

Comment: you mean `usermod`

Comment: @alrob I don't understand

Comment: the command is `usermod` not `chmod`

Comment: Oops.. Mistake. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you ! It worked for me (MacOS host, Debian guest)

Comment: Quick note, `dmode=755,fmode=644` is not needed for everyone and changes files/directories permissions in the guest.

Comment: This is a functional workaround because [clicking `Make Permanent` in the VirtualBox settings for the share doesn't actually work](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox/).

Comment: Also, a comment on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/161883/263726) states that `sudo adduser your_username vboxsf` (instead of item 2) is better because it is clearer and has better output

Comment: I have answered a question about this question: [Editing "/etc/fstab" to add a mount point: I need clearer instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1498889/editing-etc-fstab-to-add-a-mount-point-i-need-clearer-instruction).