# Editing "/etc/fstab" to add a mount point: I need clearer instruction

Tags: mount

I'm having the exact same problem solved by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1200983/263726) (trying to add a shared folder in Virtual Box, having it be owned by my user; Win host/Ubuntu guest), but I need clearer instruction:

What is the `sharedname_on_host` mentioned in the 4th item to be added to `/etc/fstab`?

> Add to /etc/fstab mount point `sharedname_on_host /xxx/xxx/ vboxsf defaults,dmode=755,fmode=644,gid=1000,uid=1000 0 0` ## gid and uid from point 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to explain the answer to [How can I change the owner of VirtualBox shared folders on Ubuntu 18.04 guest VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174556/how-can-i-change-the-owner-of-virtualbox-shared-folders-on-ubuntu-18-04-guest-vm) a bit more.

### `sharedname_on_host`

in the line

```
sharedname_on_host /xxx/xxx/ vboxsf defaults,dmode=755,fmode=644,gid=1000,uid=1000 0 0
```

refers to the name of the folder in your Windows host computer you want to share with the Ubuntu guest.

When you set up Virtual Box to share the folder you see a pop up box like this:

[image]

It is the **Folder Name** in the above picture.

Note the `/xxx/xxx/` is the mount point in the Ubuntu guest computer. There seems to be a typo. There should not be a trailing `/`. For example it could be `/home/your_username/share` or `/mnt/shared_windows_folder`.

References:

1. [How to create a shared folder in VirtualBox](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox/)
2. [How to share folders between VirtualBox guest and host](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-share-folders-between-virtualbox-guest-and-host/)

Hope this helps