# SSHFS to Windows?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, sshfs

I'm exploring Ubuntu as a guest VM on a Windows host. So far so good. Sharing a Windows folder has not yet been solved. For example, using the directions at [this site](https://www.arubacloud.com/tutorial/how-to-mount-remote-directories-with-sshfs-on-ubuntu-18-04.aspx), I tried this commmand: `sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions george@192.168.1.69://GEOLAPTOP/diet /mnt/diet`. No error was thrown; no response at all for 30 seconds so I cancelled.

My question is whether it is feasible to use `sshfs` to share a Windows folder, and if so, what command should I use? (I did discover that it's possible to do the equivalent from Windows to the guest, but that's the inverse of what I want.)

Comment: Sure it's feasible, though most VM solutions offer easier built-in sharing solutions. The Windows host must run an SSH Server. The VM networking setup must permit communication between Guest and Host (yours apparently does).

Comment: ... yeah much simpler imho to share a host folder via vboxsf - see for example [How to access a shared folder in VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161759/how-to-access-a-shared-folder-in-virtualbox)

Comment: With the guest VM an Ubuntu server, I was not able to take advantage the VirtualBox guest additions. My question in their community forum "Installing GuestAdditions eludes me" shows my effort with sharing a folder. Which is why I'm here.

Comment: OK so in that case I'd suggest either (1) persevering with the guest additions (feel free to ask an additional question here, if the link in my previous comment does not resolve it), or (2) running the SSH server on the guest and using something like WinSCP or Filezilla to connect to it from the Windows host.

Comment: As for WinSCP, I was easily able to share a Windows folder with my VM server. My experiment, though, was to the existing contents of a Windows folder at the guest. I could, of course, move contents. But since I'm just a hobbyist trying to solve a puzzle, I'll keep trying to pull from the server side rather than push from Windows. I just might take you up on the notion of an addition question here. Duty calls for now.