# Ubuntu 13.4 in virtual machine not showing wlan0

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu via virtual box in win8. If I am Connected to the internet with wifi in win8 then I could use internet in Ubuntu too. when I type,

"**ifconfig"**
it **does not show "wlan0".** it shows only eth1 and lo.
I took **editconnection->add->wifi**   but wifi range is not visible!! BUT I AM CONNECTED!!!
HOW IS THIS!!!

I DIDNT ENTER THE SECURITY KEY IN UBUNTU THEN TOO ITS CONNECTING!!! 
In virtual box setting, in USB DEVICES it doesn't show Wifi or my network adapter.

I want to know what is going inside and ***I want to manually search the wifi range and want to manually enter the security key in Ubuntu. How can I do this?***

Because when I was using Ubuntu as dual boot I was using like that. So I am curious to know about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Ubuntu on a VirtualBox and you have setup to share the networking, it should use your host's internet connection (regardless if its WIFI/LAN) and either bridge/NAT/etc it to your guest OS which is in your case Ubuntu.

Your host internet connection is provided by the eth. Naturally, since you are using VirtualBox, it is creating a virtual environment for your host system, in which your guest WLAN is not part of.

Comment: So are you saying I cant see wifi ranges in my Ubuntu? My network adapter is not showing in virtualbox.

Comment: The keyword of the day is Virtual. VirtualBox creates a "virtual computer" on your computer whcih also creates virtual hardware. Since your WLAN is physical, VirtualBox only uses its functionality as a connection to your internet. If you want to use your wifi card/adapter on Ubuntu, I suggest you do a side by side installation of Ubuntu and Windows. Otherwise, be satisfied with your VirtualBox.

Comment: I heard USB WIRELESS ADAPTER WILL WORK. iT WILL WORK OR NOT?

Comment: It might because USB devices can be chosen to be mounted from the host or guest. assuming you have the drivers, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing your wireless network card functionality is not easy from a guest.

As written in the [documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html): "[...] VirtualBox provides up to eight virtual PCI Ethernet cards for each virtual machine. [...]"

Using a WIFI USB dongle may be also a choice [wifi-card-on-an-virtualboxs-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282018/wifi-card-on-an-virtualboxs-ubuntu). If your network card is on a PCI you can try to enable [PCI passthrough](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough).