# Ubuntu won't connect to my Bell router!

Tags: 12.04, wireless, virtualbox, internet, macbook-pro

I am new to Ubuntu and I can't seem to figure out how to connect to the wireless through my Bell Router.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox on a Macbook Pro Retina, and do not have the adapter to connect over Ethernet.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to other wifi connections? Do you know the correct information to connect to your wireless? Can you say what type of security it is (WEP, WPA, WPA2, ...) ?

Comment: I found the key and IP address on the router and the security type is WEP.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to it by using the network indicator on the top panel (top right, looks like half circles)? If so, what did you do and what happened?

Comment: yes, since I have no wired connection I went into edit connections and clicked on wireless. I then went to add, but the only thing I recognized was the SSID, I have no idea what to enter in the rest or if I am even doing the right thing.

Comment: @user246559 Is the Enable Wireless option ticked on the network indicator?

Comment: The easy way to connect is to use indicator on the panel. Left click it, find your routers SSID in the list, left click on it. A pop-up will appear asking for a password. Enter the password, then click the "Connect" button at the bottom of the pop-up window. Then it should be set-up to auto connect to it when your computer is in range.

Comment: it say enable networking, but otherwise no

Comment: @DashplusJava he is using ubuntu via virtual box on osx. My thoughts are, that its virtual box settings. Please fill in all the info on the question so people can understand the situation better and have more chances for a solution.

Comment: The VirtualBox settings are working fine. could I be needing any additional drivers?

Comment: Hi! Could you please clarify these to advise you better. **1.** Are you using the same wireless or wired on your MacBook & is it working? **2.** Have you enabled NAT option on virtual box settings. **3.** Finally, may I ask for an output of your `ifconfig` please (open a terminal with `CTRL+ALT+T` & type).

Comment: @Azker Mohamed Yes I am, yes it is and I have. I don't understand the terminal, it comes up with a long list of stuff, is that the output that you want?

Comment: it is yes.. and I need the whole output of `ifconfig` posted here. also this needs to be done within the Ubuntu itself. If possible, please post a screen of your VM's network under, settings. :)

Comment: @AzkerMohamed terminal:http://postimg.org/image/rtrevdccb/            Settings: http://postimg.org/image/i7xuf2l6j/

Comment: Now I can see what the problem is. Power down your virtual machine & go into network under settings, then change the internal network to "**NAT**" if your purpose it to use internet. Let me know this works, then I'll post it as an answer for you explaining or giving you more info about the other network features. :)

Comment: It didn't work :( I read somewhere that for wireless I might need to download additional drivers, but for that I would need a wired connection.

Comment: Have you tried **bridging** your network by choosing the respective wireless adapter. Make a note that you will need to power-down your VM before making any changes. :)

Comment: @AzkerMohamed  sorry been gone for a while! Thanks this worked!! :)

Comment: Okay! I'm adding at as answer. Please accept it to reduce the questioning queue. :)

Answer (score 2):

The host should be connected to your wifi router network, the vm uses a virtual lan to connect to your host and share it's internet connection. In Ubuntu you will see a lan connection, that is what you want.

**Network Connection Journey:**

Router <----As-Wifi----> Host <----As-Virtual-Lan----> Virtual Machine

**Screenshot Of Default VirtualBox Network Settings For An Ubuntu VM:**

[image: Screenshot]

**Screenshot Of Default Network Settings Within The Ubuntu VM:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox does not natively offer Wireless support (Like a virtualized Wireless device). Instead, it connects directly to the Wireless device the Host uses. Note that VirtualBox does NOT provide a virtualized Wireless device inside the guest (ubuntu in your case). They will all look like a wired one, even if the host (osx in your case) is providing the connection via a Wired or Wireless card.

First lets install the Extension Pack for that particular VirtualBox Version. It fixes many network cases. You can find the extension pack in the [Download section of VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Your version is for OS X hosts.

To install it, open VirtualBox, go to the menu and select File --> Preferences. Now select Extensions and select the Add Pack button at the far right. Look for the downloaded Extension pack and add it to VirtualBox.

You can [read](https://askubuntu.com/a/282036/246201) this guide for detailed step-by-step with images but care, the host is ubuntu too. For example you can skip the vboxusers step.

Comment: I have a built in adapter in my mac, I do not know the make.          I tried what you mentioned in terminal but it say "not found".        I am using Ubuntu via VirtualBox but other than whats in the question that's all the info I have got for you, I truly have no idea what I am doing :|

Answer (score 0):

Virtual networking on a virtual environment holds few types which can be used according to the users need. Depending on how the network that a user requires; they can select their preferred one. But before doing so; it is better to acknowledge on the available options & what it does.

Basic networks explained;

- **Not attached** - In this mode, VirtualBox reports to the guest that a network card is present, but that there is no connection -- as if no Ethernet cable was plugged into the card. This way it is possible to "pull" the virtual Ethernet cable and disrupt the connection, which can be useful to inform a guest operating system that no network connection is available and enforce a reconfiguration.
- **Network Address Translation (NAT)** - If you're a use who need web browsing, email communication, downloading within the guest OS. Well, this is the suitable one as it look into the host OS's network and NAT it into guest OS
- **Bridged networking** - This is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations and running servers in a guest. When enabled, VirtualBox connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network stack. In simple ways, this does the same as the host OS tend to do.
- **Internal networking** - This can be used to create a different kind of software-based network which is visible to selected virtual machines, but not to applications running on the host or to the outside world.
- **Host-only networking** - This can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among virtual machines and the host.
- **Generic networking** - Rarely used modes share the same generic network interface, by allowing the user to select a driver which can be included with VirtualBox or be distributed in an extension pack.

These are the common available networking types available on Virtual Box environment. You may refer **[Chapter 6. Virtual networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)** for detailed information.

Now, by looking into your issue; I assume you will need to bridge adapter in order to get wireless working. But I'm quiet confused as to why **NAT** did not work as it suppose to. Further, selecting network types are located under;

- **VirtualBox** -> **Select VM** -> **Settings** -> **Networking** (do below);

[image]

Hope this helps!