# Unable to find the wifi symbol at the top right corner

Tags: wireless

I am a newbie to Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 in VMware. Everything went perfectly, but I was unable to find the wifi symbol in the notification area in the top right corner of the desktop.

I have tried changing the memory allocation to 1GB, but even then it wasn't detecting the wifi. I also tried changing the network connection in the VMware Virtual Machine Settings to Bridged network connection. It just got disconnected from a wired connection and reconnected to that.

Can anyone please help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/282018/wifi-card-on-an-virtualboxs-ubuntu) might be of help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wireless Network in Virtualbox](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178804/wireless-network-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to solve your problem with the missing networking applet icon if you gave your virtual machine more RAM. Set this configuration parameter for the virtual machine in the virtual machine settings editor (*VM* -> *Settings* -> *Memory*). The guest memory size should not be set lower than the minimum recommendations of the operating system provider, which is 768MB RAM for Ubuntu 13.04.

If you have a wifi connection in your host machine, then you should also have the same wifi connection in your virtual machine in VMware, if you have configured the networking in VMware to use the same network connection as the host machine is using, which is called a *bridged network connection*. A bridged network connection connects the guest virtual machine directly to the physical network of the host machine. The screenshot below is from the Virtual Machine Settings screen in VMware.

[image]

Comment: thak you for your response karel...i'had tried changing the memory allocation to 1gb.. even then it was'nt detecting the wifi.

Comment: @user3194553 The comment was helpful, so I added more info about your wifi internet connection to my answer.

Comment: ya i'd just tried that..it's just got disconnected from a wired connection and reconnected to that...

Comment: What does running this command: `sudo lshw -C network` in the terminal show? If it's too big for a comment, just edit your question and add the results to your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can open your unity dash and search for `Network Connections` application, this will simply be the same as if you click that indicator on the up right hand side :)

Comment: yaa i checked that..it's displaying only the ethernet nothing more,is this is due to lack of wireless drivers??