# Can't use Wireless Network in Virtualbox?

Tags: wireless, 14.04, virtualbox

I'm trying to enable Wireless on VirtualBox in my Ubuntu 14.04 in a Kali Linux, but this OS does not show the wi-fi for me to connect.

[image: Kali Linux config dialog]

After I turn on the OS the wi-fi doesn't show up

[image: Kali desktop, no wifi]

I already tried [Wifi card on Ubuntu in VirtualBox, no wireless extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282018/wifi-card-on-an-virtualboxs-ubuntu) and others, but I still can't enable the wireless.