# No wireless interface found in ubuntu 18.04 running within virtual machine

Tags: 18.04, wireless, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to use the `iwconfig` command to list all my wireless device interface, but I'm getting nothing:

```
root@ubuntu:~# iwconfig
```

Result:

```
ens33     no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: The Wireless Adapter is never exposed to the guest VM directly.  Which is why it doesn't show up.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/282018/wifi-card-on-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-no-wireless-extensions and https://askubuntu.com/questions/178804/wireless-network-in-virtualbox go into detail on this