# Latest Ubuntu server 22.04.2 without install Intel AX200 WIFI Driver

Tags: wireless, intel

Intel AX200 WIFI Driver is work in Win11, I installed ubuntu server thru virtual box 7.0.8.
I tried check with below and disable fast-boot in asus TUF B550-plus boot:　
https://jianjiesun.medium.com/ubuntu-20-04-intel-ax200-wifi-driver-install-2ac4c0dc4601

sudo lshw -C network
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8YhK.jpg)

uname -r
5.15.0-71-generic

ls -l /etc/modprobe.d/
iwlwifi.conf

ls -l /lib/firmware/ grep | iwlwifi-cc-a0
I can find iwlwifi-cc-a0-46.ucode inside it

but none wifi w* interface in
cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

network:
ethernets:
enp0s3:
dhcp4: true
version: 2

May I know how to turn wifi driver install and up in ubuntu ?
now, it only have ethernet driver installed, but I need use wifi.

Comment: You will need to use PCI passthrough in vmware, https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1010789

Comment: I am using virtual box.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/pcipassthrough.html

Comment: After install extension pack, need reinstall  ubuntu server?

Comment: Shouldn't need to, if the PCI passthrough works, you should see a change in results for `lshw -C network`

Comment: See this passage, i will try later https://askubuntu.com/questions/282018/wifi-card-on-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-no-wireless-extensions

Comment: I installed extension pack, turn wifi as ethernet  as above link passage. I can ping www.google.com in ubuntu server.  But i cannot use https: //ip:9090 outside after cockpit is installed.  Any more hint how I can use browser to access my ubuntu server (installed thru virtual machine) ?

Comment: I seems get this work, after checking ip a, with the correct ip.