# I cannot use apt-get update

Tags: wireless, 13.04, server, apt

I have **Ubuntu 13.04 Server** on a Virtual Box which is using 2GB of ram and 20GB of space. It's freshly installed and I cannot use apt-get update.

I have tried the same on an **Ubuntu 12.10 Server** but it still doesn't work.

Every time I type apt-get update I get

```
0% [Connecting to ca.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.202)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.15)]
```

Which then hangs for about 20 minutes, and then this displays

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a 80]
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a 80]
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a 80]
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-backports/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1a 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

However I can ping the IP address and domain on the server, and I can access it on my Host machine browser

```
davidrockin@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ ping -c 2  ca.archive.ubuntu.com
PING ca.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ragana.canonical.com (91.189.91.13): icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=42.0 ms
64 bytes from ragana.canonical.com (91.189.91.13): icmp_req=2 ttl=49 time=43.3 ms

--- ca.archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 42.088/42.742/43.396/0.654 ms
davidrockin@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ ping -c 2 91.189.92.202
PING 91.189.92.202 (91.189.92.202) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.92.202: icmp_req=1 ttl=49 time=101 ms
p64 bytes from 91.189.92.202: icmp_req=2 ttl=49 time=98.9 ms

--- 91.189.92.202 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 98.976/100.335/101.695/1.395 ms
davidrockin@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ ping -c 3 security.ubuntu.com
PING security.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from orobas.canonical.com (91.189.91.14): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=112 ms
64 bytes from orobas.canonical.com (91.189.91.14): icmp_req=2 ttl=52 time=44.5 ms
^C64 bytes from orobas.canonical.com (91.189.91.14): icmp_req=3 ttl=52 time=41.0 ms

--- security.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 41.038/66.103/112.679/32.967 ms
```

I have tried modifying my **/etc/apt/sources.list** file to use a different respository

This is my current **/etc/apt/sources.list** file, which is the original file that was created when Ubuntu Installed.

```
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
```

I have tried restarting my computer, reinstalling my Virtual Machine, restarting my router many times, modifying the sources.list, and I have been googling for several hours, and can't figure out why it's not working.

I have also attempted to disable IPv6 (http://www.bearfruit.org/2013/05/06/ubuntu-server-having-ipv6-probs-its-easy-to-disable/)

Last night I had setup an Ubuntu Server to test it out, and apt-get update worked last night. Now, it's not working anymore on a new Virtual Machine. The one I created yesterday was deleted, and the new one I created today is not working.

My host machine is a laptop and I am using wifi, the specs of it is

```
Windows 7
8GB Ram
658 GB HDD (214 GB used)
AMD A8-3520M APU
```

**Edit:** I am not behind a proxy/vpn, and my internet connection is fine.

Comment: Can you connect trough SSL from within Virtual Box? First off all turn the Windows firewall off briefly. If this not works,take a look at this answer:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/178804/wireless-network-in-virtualbox

Comment: My firewall is disabled and the network adapter for the virtual machine is not a NAT but a bridged adapter

Comment: @DavidTkachuk try `ping6 -c3 ca.archive.ubuntu.com` and `ping6 -c3 security.ubuntu.com`. Also, change your DNS for Google's or OpenDNS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realizing I am stupid, it had nothing to do with the repositories or the Virtual Machine configuration.

All I had to do, was disable firewall on avast. Something I completely forgot about.

Comment: i'm in your shoes i believe, but i don't want to disable firewall on main host and wanted to get internet access on my VM, i tried allowing traffic on virtual bridge /interface my VM on. still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is using ipv6 to apt-get and ipv4 to ping. It might be worth a try to disable ipv6 with a kernel parameter though I haven't needed to do this in a long time myself. In /etc/default/grub add `ipv6.disable=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=...` then `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Disabling IPv6 worked for me, but rather than changing kernel parameters I followed http://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: sysctl.conf and enabling sysctl, awesome, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I had this problem because we have a corporate proxy and I was using sudo:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but the `http_proxy` env var got left behind...  Switching to:

```
sudo -E apt-get update
```

got everything rolling again.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: the problem in terminal try to use main root terminal, Linux has two terminals ,try to use root terminals

```
$ sudo passwd root
[sudo] password for ramesh:
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
```

this for root setup ,

Case 2: to install sudo pack properly ,if sudo commands are not working

type this in terminal

```
tar -xzf archive.tar.gz
```

or this

```
tar -xzf archive-name.tar.gz
cd archive-name
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

case 3 : if the above commands are not working try to use these commands

to check whats wrong in the terminal

```
auto-apt run <command_string>
```

or

```
apt-get check
```

or

```
dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config
```

Comment: I tried apt-get update again using root, but there's no difference. It still doesn't update and hangs

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect from behind the proxy server, then ensure the correct proxy setting are done at

```
vi /etc/apt/apt.conf 
Acquire::http::Proxy "http_colon//proxyserverip:proxyport";
```

then try

```
apt-get update
```

This should see you through the issue.