# How to disable IPv6 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, ipv6

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. And I have done the following to disable **ipv6**.

I have open `/etc/sysctl.conf` using `gedit` and paste the following lines at the end of `sysctl.conf`.

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

But when I check it using following command,

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

I am getting result as '0'( i.e still Enabled). Please help me to disable ipv6, so that I can use hadoop.

I followed instructions from [this link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).

Answer (score 230, accepted):

To disable ipv6, you have to open `/etc/sysctl.conf` using any text editor and insert the following lines at the end:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

If ipv6 is still not disabled, then the problem is that `sysctl.conf` is still not activated.

To solve this, open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the command,

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

You will see this in the terminal:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

After that, if you run:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

It will report:

```
1
```

If you see `1`, ipv6 has been successfully disabled.

Comment: will value 1 hold after reboot?

Comment: @Georjia yes... after this ipv6 will disable permanently.... untill you enable it...

Comment: even with `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` reporting disabled (1), ubuntu x64 14.04 still manages to somehow autoconfig an a v6 ip on the main interface (ipv6 is set to auto in the network manager by default)

Comment: if ipv6 is disabled in kernel this dont work beacuse cant find /proc/sys/net/ipv6/  .  There must be another way too.

Comment: I did get the same issue too. For a while the ipv6 was disabled, but I started getting boot messages about it again.

Comment: I tried this (getting the `1`), and the advice from Mostafa below - yet `ipv6` still appears in my `dmesg` and slows down my boot - what can I do? `[   19.434645] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eno1: link is not ready`

Comment: if ipv6 is still respawning Mostafa Ahangarha Answer is worth trying - I am using that an many machines to completely disable ipv6 system wide without any problems so far

Comment: I tend to avoid directly editing the config file if there is a `someapp.conf.d` directory available. On my system there is `/etc/sysctl.d/` with many config files for various settings. I created a new one called `30-noipv6.conf` and put the settings from above in and then loaded it with `sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/30-noipv6.conf`.

Answer (score 18):

You might want to disable it right from the boot. For this purpose, open `/etc/default/grub` with your favorite text editor with root access (maybe `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`.

In this file, find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 quiet splash"
```

Save the file and update grub by running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

=============================
Mint 19 and Ubuntu 18.04:

on Mint 19 it would be "xed admin:///etc/default/grub" and maybe on Ubuntu 18.04 "gedit admin:///etc/default/grub" to get a GUI editor for doing the edits to the file.  The rest of the steps will be the same.

Comment: Why and when do we want to disable using GRUB instead of setting the sysctl?

Comment: There has been cases in which I failed to disable ipv6 using sysctl. I think last time it happened few month ago while I was configuring my Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score -2):

In addition to Ross Rogers answer above you should add:

```
sudo nano /etc/init/scip.conf

# description "Start sysctl at boot"

description "sysctl"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

console log

respawn
respawn limit unlimited

exec /sbin/sysctl -p
```

Comment: Why? What does it do?

Comment: It looks like it runs sysctl -p when booting to runlevel 2,3,4, and 5.  However there's this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/654291/i-cant-get-any-information-or-help-about-an-init-process-called-scip-which-ha that implies this scip.conf thing doesn't really work.

Comment: sysctl runs on its own at boot, so this is wrong..