# Should I replace the customized configuration file during release upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I'm upgrading ubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04, during the upgrade it is asking the following question:

> **Replace the customized configuration file '/etc/sysctl.conf'?**
>
> You will lose any changes made to this configuration file if you
>   choose to replace it with the newer version.
>
> Difference between the files:
>
> ```
> --- /etc/sysctl.conf  2014-04-21 21:38:34.970070205 +0530
>
> +++ /etc/sysctl.conf.dpkg-new 2013-04-01 07:55:31.000000000 +0530
> @@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
>  #
>  # /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables
> -# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables
> +# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
>  # See sysctl.conf (5) for information.
>  #
>
> @@ -58,7 +58,3 @@
>  # Log Martian Packets
>  #net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
>  #
> -# disable ipv6
> -net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
> -net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
> -net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
> ```

I don't understand what this means, I tried googling for an answer but every post has a different file name for the same question and the answers are varying. Should I keep the file or replace it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During release (or package) upgrades, the package manager usually gives you a few options:

1. Keep your version.
2. Keep the package maintainer's version.
3. Show the difference.
4. Do an (experimental) three-way merge.
5. Open a shell.

With (1) and (2), no file is discarded. With (1), the package maintainer's version is saved with the extension `dpkg-dist`, and with (2), your version is saved with the extension `dpkg-old`. You're using (3). I have never used the other two, hopefully someone who has will come along and post an answer.

I personally always choose (1), and then manually merge in the changes (if they're worthwile) after upgrade - though I assume (5) can be used to do this.

Note that this prompt comes up **only** if the file was modified outside the package management system (that is, by a user, like you). So the changes were presumably made by you for a reason, and usually you'd still want those changes around.

Comment: If you choose to open a shell, you get a root shell (env seems as if you had used `sudo -i`) and when you type `exit` you get the same menu options again. I once found this useful; after seeing that `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` had been updated, I made separate `blacklist-<module>.conf` files for my custom blacklists (additions were made by a script I use to modify the iso at install time - must improve the script so it makes separate files in future). After that, I closed the shell and installed the package maintainer's version of the blacklist.

Answer (score 1):

Over the past few days I've been upgrading a system from 12.10 -> 13.04 -> 13.10 -> 14.04.1LTS, one upgrade per day, and it was only the last stage it complained about sysctl.conf. I think what is going on is that between 13.10 to 14.04 someone added a full stop at the end of one of the comments! That is enough to get it to start complaining.

As muru's answer said, I chose to keep what was already in there (in my case it is `net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_notify = 1`, which I assume Rackspace put there, as the comment above mentions xen).

Answer (score 1):

It's a diff output comparing the before and after files.

Lines added in the new file are marked as +, lines removed with -.  The other lines starting with a ' ' are just for context.

Specifically it means:

```
-# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables
+# See /etc/sysctl.d/ for additional system variables.
```

The old version didn't have a full stop at the end of the comment, the new one does.  Trivial.

```
-# disable ipv6
-net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
-net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
-net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

The old version had lines about disabling ipv6 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6, [How to disable IPv6 in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04)) the new one does not have these lines.

You should keep the file unless you want to enable IPv6.