# lxc-create hangs and finally fails

Tags: 14.04, server, juju, maas, lxc

I was trying to place some juju charms on linux containers and the containers failed to start. To debug the issue I sshed into the node where this happened and tried creating an LXC container manually like

```
ubuntu@slot13:~$ sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n pavan
Checking cache download in /var/cache/lxc/trusty/rootfs-amd64 ...
Installing packages in template: ssh,vim,language-pack-en
Downloading ubuntu trusty minimal ...
I: Retrieving Release
```

It isn't making any progress at all. Its stuck here for a long long time. After a really long time it says,

```
ERROR: Unable to fetch GPG key from keyserver
```

and continues to hang. Finally after 20-30 mins, it gives up like

```
E: Failed getting release file http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
```

Where are the log files corresponding to `lxc-create` command? How can I debug this issue?

**EDIT**: I figured out how to see the debug logs and hence ran the below command a few times

```
sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n pavan --logfile=test.txt --logpriority=DEBUG
```

`test.txt` contains only this

```
lxc-create 1414897265.204 ERROR    lxc_container - Error: pavan creation was not completed
lxc-create 1414897407.757 ERROR    lxc_container - Error: pavan creation was not completed
lxc-create 1414897407.759 WARN     lxc_log - lxc_log_init called with log already initialized
```

But still it hangs and the debug logs aren't offering much help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you behind a proxy? if yes, then you may set your proxy in bash. Issue following,

```
export http_proxy="http://<proxy_host>:<port>"
```

Comment: I think you were right about the proxy. I added this in the proxy host and it worked
`iptables -t nat -IPOSTROUTING -s 10.10.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE` where 10.10.10.10 is the host IP

Comment: Hello,Please can you explain more the problem and the soltuion, because i have the same error ?

Comment: root@localhost:/home# iptables -t nat -IPOSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.1/16 -j MASQUERADE
root@localhost:/home# sudo lxc-create -t ubuntu -n u1 -- -r trusty -a amd64
Checking cache download in /var/cache/lxc/trusty/rootfs-amd64 ... 
Installing packages in template: ssh,vim,language-pack-en
Downloading ubuntu trusty minimal ...
I: Retrieving Release 
................................ it is blocked

Comment: @Pradeeper : Please, i'd like to test your solution. export http_proxy="http://<proxy_host>:<port>" but what values can i choose for "port" and "proxy_host" is the IP @ ?

Comment: You have to issue this command in a terminal. If you don't use specif port on your proxy and use port 80 then ignore the port section above.  If above fixed your issue, then you can add that line to your .bashrc file or /etc/profile

Answer (score 8):

Please append `--no-validate` flag to skip gpg validation:

```
lxc-create -t ubuntu -n pavan -- --no-validate
```

Refer https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/master/templates/lxc-download.in#L240

Comment: Note it's important to use `-- --no-validate` not `--no-validate`: the last one isn't valid. I edited the answer with the correct example.

Answer (score 2):

Actually juju uses the 'ubuntu-cloud' template to grab an image, the command executed to create the template in my system running trusty is:

```
lxc-create -n juju-trusty-lxc-template \
  -t ubuntu-cloud \
  -f /var/lib/juju/containers/juju-trusty-lxc-template/lxc.conf \
  -- --debug \
  --userdata /var/lib/juju/containers/juju-trusty-lxc-template/cloud-init \
  --hostid juju-trusty-lxc-template
  -r trusty
```

I suggest you to run something like that and see what error gives you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Felipe for the workaround - for a complete fix, required also doing:

```
mkdir /var/lib/lxc/juju-trusty-lxc-template/rootfs/var/log/juju
```

Details:

1. ran lxc-create as per above Felipe's updateList item
2. deploying any service was consistently failing, juju status showing:

   ```
   agent-state-info: 'container failed to start and was destroyed: jjo-local-machine-1'
   ```
3. found at /var/lib/juju/containers/jjo-local-machine-5/container.log :

   ```
   lxc-start 1427066682.951 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:mount_entry:1711 - No such file or directory - failed to mount '/var/log/juju-jjo-local' on '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/var/log/juju'
   ```
4. Creating the directory fixed it, further deploys ok:

   ```
    mkdir /var/lib/lxc/juju-trusty-lxc-template/rootfs/var/log/juju
   ```

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem

If you are behind a firewall that restricts internet access, you could get this error:

```
$ lxc-create -t download -n my-container
Setting up the GPG keyring
ERROR: Unable to fetch GPG key from keyserver.
lxc-create: lxccontainer.c: create_run_template: 1297 container
  creation template for my-container failed
lxc-create: tools/lxc_create.c: main: 318 Error creating
  container my-container
```

#### Fix

Connect to the key server through port 80:

```
$ lxc-create -t download -n my-container \
  -- --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80
```

#### Details

The key server, `hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80`, is from the `lxc` source code:

```
apt source lxc
grep -ri hkp: .
```

#### References

- [Launchpad bug 1331920](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxc/+bug/1331920)
- [Launchpad bug 1609479](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-ansible/+bug/1609479)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. We have a proxyserver with a wrong http/1.0 implementation making trouble with gpg keyserver fetch. As a workaround, the key can be added manually by doing the following things:

Got to http://keyserver.ubuntu.com and search for the following key: 0xBAEFF88C22F6E216 (found in /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download search for DOWNLOAD_KEYID). Download it and save it to a file named keyfile

Now the saved file can be added to the system keyring for e.g. by using

```
sudo apt-key add keyfile
```

There are more ways to add it, but using ubuntu this is a working way. Maybe you can also use gpg directly. After adding there is no longer a need for lxc to contact the keyserver and the problem was fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an [answer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxc/+bug/1331920/comments/5) in [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxc/+bug/1331920), i found out that disabling IPV6 should work. And it worked for me.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04) stack overflow answer shows how to do it.