# lxc/kvm containers fail to start

Tags: juju, maas, kvm-virtualization, openstack, lxc

I have MAAS+Juju setup ready and was successfully able to deploy some openstack charms on specific machines. Then, I read that its safe and good practice to place these openstack charms in their own containers. I tried

```
juju deploy --to lxc:14  --repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/keystone
```

Charm was added successfully but `juju stat` shows

```
  "14":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.10
    dns-name: slot13.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-9cf5e120-5625-11e4-b22e-a41f72f16283/
    series: trusty
    containers:
      14/kvm/0:
        agent-state-info: 'kvm container creation failed: exit status 1'
        instance-id: pending
        series: trusty
      14/lxc/0:
        agent-state-info: container failed to start
        instance-id: pending
        series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=4 mem=32768M
```

I tried with kvm containers with the same result ( you can see even that error above. For KVM containers, I did enable Virtualization tech in BIOS ).

`juju debug-log` shows

```
machine-14: 2014-11-05 06:31:12 ERROR juju.container.lxc clonetemplate.go:167 container failed to start: container failed to start
machine-14: 2014-11-05 06:31:12 ERROR juju.provisioner.lxc lxc-broker.go:97 failed to start container: container failed to start
machine-14: 2014-11-05 06:31:12 ERROR juju.provisioner provisioner_task.go:418 cannot start instance for machine "14/lxc/0": container failed to start
```

There are no service/charm(keystone) specific logs at /var/log/juju on the target node. This is happening with all services that I wish to place in a container, not only keystone or openstack services.

**Note**: I had a problem with `lxc-create` on the target node because of some proxy issues and I think that my [earlier post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544597/lxc-create-hangs-and-finally-fails) on this solved that issue. But the issue I describe in this question doesn't go away.

**EDIT**: I found the container failure logs and am pasting the same here-

```
 lxc-start 1415307100.508 INFO     lxc_conf - mount points have been setup
      lxc-start 1415307100.508 WARN     lxc_conf - rootfs specified but no console found at '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/dev/console'
      lxc-start 1415307100.508 ERROR    lxc_conf - No such file or directory - failed to create symlink for kmsg
      lxc-start 1415307100.508 ERROR    lxc_conf - failed to setup kmsg for 'juju-machine-14-lxc-1'
      lxc-start 1415307100.508 INFO     lxc_conf - 0 tty(s) has been setup
      lxc-start 1415307100.508 ERROR    lxc_conf - No such file or directory - Error creating /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/dev/fd
      lxc-start 1415307100.508 ERROR    lxc_conf - failed to setup /dev symlinks for 'juju-machine-14-lxc-1'
      lxc-start 1415307100.508 ERROR    lxc_start - failed to setup the container
      lxc-start 1415307100.508 ERROR    lxc_sync - invalid sequence number 1. expected 2
      lxc-start 1415307100.508 WARN     lxc_conf - failed to remove interface '(null)'
      lxc-start 1415307100.540 ERROR    lxc_start - failed to spawn 'juju-machine-14-lxc-1'
      lxc-start 1415307100.540 WARN     lxc_commands - command get_init_pid failed to receive response
      lxc-start 1415307100.540 WARN     lxc_cgmanager - do_cgm_get exited with error
      lxc-start 1415307105.545 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - The container failed to start.
      lxc-start 1415307105.545 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - To get more details, run the container in foreground mode.
      lxc-start 1415307105.545 ERROR    lxc_start_ui - Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

The first error `rootfs specified but no console found at '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/dev/console'` is indeed right in the sense that there is no path `'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/dev/console'`. The dir structure ends at '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lxc/`

Comment: Ugh... those logs are impossible to decrypt. "container failed to start: container failed to start" why tell me the same *twice*? I would report a bug asking that the logs provide less redundant/more relevant information to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. Not exactly the same, but the solution was to remove the lxcs.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/lxc/offending-container-xx
rm -rf /var/lib/juju/containers/offending-container-xx
```

If someone comes across a similar error, hopefully this will help.