# Kernel Panic on xubuntu toughbook cf-19

Tags: kernel, xubuntu

I'm on a toughbook cf 19 xubuntu and I have a kernel panic about 10 times a day. Do you know what can be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Since the call trace has inet6_... on top of it, I'd suggest network driver / APIC issues. Disable ipv6 if you use ipv4 only (http://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04). Also running the kernel with `noapic nolapic` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Xubuntu. Reinstalling can usually fix these problems. If that doesn't work, it may be that the disk is damaged. If that seems like the case, try burning a new disk and reinstalling Xubuntu using the new disk. Note that there is [a glitch where it deletes your Windows partition if you have one](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/08/ubuntu-installer-bug-wipes-partitions).