# Firefox is slow

Tags: 14.04, firefox

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (workstation), and it's like Firefox is very slow (compared to the same on an old windows machine... sorry again for the reference, but I thought it would be as fast or faster than on windows). I haven't installed any add-ons or try to tune up by myself by the time.

Firefox is the 35.0.1 and thought it was slow on a Ubuntu 14.04 Server too.
Is it something normal on Ubuntu?

Do I have to modify some settings on Firefox or Ubuntu to tune up this?

Comment: This question is unfortunately too broad to answer *as is*. I can tell you, that I do not have problems on my own machine, but that doesn't help you.

Comment: Thanks it helps in fact, it means that it's possibly my machine, but Ubuntu is not slow by the way... so that's why I thought it could come from Firefox default configuration... If nobody has the same problem, it may means that it comes from me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is slow?  Switching between tabs, opening a site, scrolling the window...?  It might be your graphic drivers. If you have an nVidia card try installing the non-free nVidia drivers rather than the stock ones that come with Ubuntu.

UPDATE:
Okay, if it's the network access that is slow my guess would be that you have IPv6 enabled. Try running `sudo apt-get update` from a terminal window, and if you get the same 5-10 second pause then try disabling IPv6. The "quick" way to do that (just for testing) would be to edit `/etc/gai.conf` and add the following line to it:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

Restart firefox and see if that speeds things up. If it does, a better way to disable IPv6 is described in this answer to the question [How to disable IPv6 in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6)

Comment: Loading a web page is slow, opening a new tab is really fast.
My Internet connection is quite ok, loading web page on other system is normal... I'll get a look on my graphic drivers thanks

Comment: @Charles thanks, I've run the update, then I've uncommented the line "precedence..." on /etc/gai.conf, and after restarting Firefox it's much better! thanks a lot