# What is Network-manager trying to do with rdisc?

Tags: networking, network-manager, firewall

I have quite strict firewall setup using (g)ufw, allowing only some known to be useful outgoing traffic and denying the rest.

I have noticed these recurring messages in syslog, and I'm wondering what nm is trying to achieve:

```
Mar 13 11:50:42 NetworkManager[1106]: <error> [1426243842.961433] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:241] send_rs(): (eth0): cannot send router solicitation: -1.
Mar 13 11:50:43 NetworkManager[1106]: <error> [1426243843.959533] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:241] send_rs(): (wlan0): cannot send router solicitation: -1.
Mar 13 11:50:46 NetworkManager[1106]: <error> [1426243846.960535] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:241] send_rs(): (eth0): cannot send router solicitation: -1.
Mar 13 11:50:47 NetworkManager[1106]: <error> [1426243847.959683] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:241] send_rs(): (wlan0): cannot send router solicitation: -1.
Mar 13 11:50:50 NetworkManager[1106]: <error> [1426243850.962048] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:241] send_rs(): (eth0): cannot send router solicitation: -1.
Mar 13 11:50:51 NetworkManager[1106]: <error> [1426243851.959510] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:241] send_rs(): (wlan0): cannot send router solicitation: -1.
Mar 13 11:50:54 NetworkManager[1106]: <error> [1426243854.961697] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:241] send_rs(): (eth0): cannot send router solicitation: -1.
Mar 13 11:50:55 NetworkManager[1106]: <error> [1426243855.958850] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:241] send_rs(): (wlan0): cannot send router solicitation: -1.
Mar 13 11:50:58 NetworkManager[1106]: <error> [1426243858.960156] [rdisc/nm-lndp-rdisc.c:241] send_rs(): (eth0): cannot send router solicitation: -1.
Mar 13 11:50:58 kernel: [ 2909.789897] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:3e97:0eff:fe0e:5113 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0002 LEN=48 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=133 CODE=0
```

Is this related to my firewall rules ?
Can this be desactivated ?

Comment: Looks like your firewall rules are a bit too strict...  Do you use WiFi HotSpots regularly?  How many profiles do you use (built-in ones are Office, Public, Home)  Can you post the output of `sudo ufw status` and `sudo iptables --list`?

Comment: @Fabby I am indeed blocking most outgoing traffic, be it IPV4 or IPV6 and only open streams I know I need. I'm currently reading through this: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4890.txt I'll come back when done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These NetworkManager errors and UFW blocking are related to router solicitation messages. `ICMPv6 TYPE=133` are your host originating requests  for IPv6 configuration.

- **If you use IPv6**, add a rule in (g)ufw: **Policy: Allow, Direction: Out, To: ff02::2** and the messages won't appear any more.
- **If you don't use IPv6**, disable it by following the [answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: I have opened a bug report on ufw for this, and proposed a patch to allow router solicitation by default: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ufw/+bug/1434525

Comment: What about if I'm just using plain iptables and ip6tables? How do I allow router solicitation messages?