# Postfix doesnt know own hostname

Tags: server, dns, email, postfix, localhost

in my postfix logs I often see that postfix failed to send an email to root@levinus [my hostname] because theres no DNS record for levinus. But in my /etc/hosts is an entry for levinus (--> 127.0.0.1 AND my static IP). With ping I can reach levinus, then I ping myself. But why postfix doesnt accepts the /etc/hosts entrys?

Piece of the postfix log:

```
BC59A2FE000B: to=<root@levinus>, relay=none, delay=0.03,    
delays=0.01/0/0.02/0, dsn=5.4.4, status=bounced (Host or domain name not   
found. Name service error for name=levinus type=AAAA: Host not found)
Oct 11 14:47:29 levinus postfix/qmgr[29217]: BC59A2FE000B: removed
```

Part of /etc/hosts:

```
[STATIC IP] levinus
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost levinus
```

System is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

//Edit
With inet_protocols = ipv4 in main.cfg from postfix the same. Only the error message is another (type = A).
When I add levinus to the IPv6 entry ::1 in /etc/hosts its the same (type = AAAA)

//Edit2
postfix logs even with the `levinus` hostname:

```
Oct 12 14:40:33 levinus postfix/smtpd[10103]: connect from levinus[127.0.0.1]
Oct 12 14:40:33 levinus postfix/smtpd[10103]: disconnect from levinus[127.0.0.1]
```

But all mails too root@levinus are still bounced.

Even when I edit the /etc/nsswitch.conf to `hosts: files` only postfix dont knew the own hostname. Before it was set to `hosts: files dns`.

Comment: `AAAA` record is different from `A` record. `AAAA` is for IPv6, the one you have in /etc/hosts is IPv4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with IPv4 address but IPv6 due to `AAAA` record is not exist.

This can be resolved by switching postfix to use only IPv4. `sudo postconf -e 'inet_protocols = ipv4'` then reload postfix.

Comment: Edited question, i isnt a solution :(

Comment: check in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` which option is the first one for `dns` line?

Comment: There wasnt a dns line, only the hosts line with the option dns:

    `hosts:          files dns`

Comment: Have you any idea for a solution to this?

Comment: you need to disable IPv6 . Use this [guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Ipv6 is disabled, its the same problem, in the log is only shown type = A instead of type = AAAA.

Comment: you can ignore this because `levinus` does not have entry in DNS record, its working as design, trying to lookup on DNS and then no entry (this is when you see the information on log) then continue with `hosts`. `A` and `AAAA` record error is associated to DNS not `hosts` file.

Comment: But the log means that the mail is even bounced and it seems so: the mail is repeatet ~ 300 times per day. I dont know with program is sending the mail too.