# Randomly losing WiFi connectivity

Tags: wireless, drivers, connection

I can't handle inbound or outbound data. Sometimes I even get disconnected. It happens very often though not always. It happens at some points in the WiFi area while it does not happen that often at others. However, none of this is consistent. All other devices and laptops work as desired. I tried with a live 15.10 and worked without any problem. Something's off on my current 14.04 LTS installation. The card is internal:

```
description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless 7260
vendor: Intel Corporation
```

Any suggestion? I don't really know how to troubleshoot this issues. It might have something to do with USB port drivers since something similar happens too with the integrated webcam.

Comment: Just a guess, but try disabling ipv6 - http://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. May I ask how this would solve it? Why do you think ipv6 can be causing this?

Comment: I had a similar problem on my wireless card. After trying lots of fixes, it was because ipv6 was timing out. disabling ipv6 is easy and may solve your issue also.