# Issues with disabling iPv6 on Ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: networking, configuration, ipv6, hadoop

To disable iPv6 on Ubuntu 14.0.4 (LTS) I added these lines in *sysctl.conf* file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Since I was getting 0, when I used the command:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

As informed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04), I followed the steps given. When I tried to use:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

I'm getting an output in the Terminal as:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

I have checked the directory and found that the file/directory is present.

Additional information: I'm trying to install Apache Hadoop (ver. 2.7.2) in my system. Though all the services are up and running, I am unsure if it will work with my network configuration. Since it is informed ([here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopIPv6)) that Hadoop doesn't work well with iPv6 connection, so I tried to run:

```
sudo sed -i 's/net.ipv6.bindv6only\ =\ 1/net.ipv6.bindv6only\ =\ 0/' \/etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf && sudo invoke-rc.d procps restart
```

When I do this, I get a message:

```
sed: can't read /etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf: No such file or directory
```

**There is no such file in the directory when I searched manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do, if you really want to do this, is to see to that the `inet6` module isn't loaded when the computer reboots.

Just try this (as `root` user).

```
$ cat >/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ipv6.conf <<EOF
# Turn of IPv6 by blacklisting the module.
# Even though it isn't needed.
blacklist ipv6

EOF
$
```

But really, you shouldn't need to do this. As long as you don't have a IPv6 network in your LAN, it will not interfere with your IPv4 net.

Don't forget to remove those changes you have added to `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: I guess I will leave it like that since it is working fine for now. If problem arises then will go through this.

Comment: That sounds like an ok choice. But I would still recommend that you don't stop IPv6. And as I wrote, the simplest and secure way to turn off IPv6 is to just remove and blacklist the module `ipv6`.

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop page you linked to is really not saying that IPv6 will cause you problems. What it is saying will cause you problems is if you turn off IPv4 and try to use IPv6 instead.

So, your goal shouldn't be to get rid of IPv6. It should be to leave IPv4 working.

Now, the page does mention a configuration option that they recommend setting. It has to do with how Hadoop would register with the OS to listen for incoming requests. Ubuntu gives you the option to register to listen for only IPv4 connections, only IPv6, or both.

Some (older, I'm pretty sure) versions of Debian (which Ubuntu is based on) thought they would try to help apps with the transition, and changed some settings with how what listening setup would work. **That** setting is what the wiki page you mentioned is referring to. To turn it off, you just need to put the following in the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0
```

and while you are there, remove the lines:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then run `sysctl -p` and you should be all set.