# I blacklisted IPv6. Want to undo

Tags: ipv6

So, I followed [this answer on this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748636/issues-with-disabling-ipv6-on-ubuntu-14-0-4/748784) and now I want to undo the changes.

How do I even know something has changed?
And if something changed, how would I undo it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  A quick scan of your provided link showed it blacklisted `ipv6`.  If this is all you did, you only need remove those lines (which if you followed the accepted answer, was 2 comments that do nothing except document what you did, and the blacklist line).  I'd use my favorite editor & comment out the blacklist line (eg. sudo vim `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ipv6.conf`), but you could also just remove the file...  If it were me, I'd also check your history (looking for when you did it; I add date/time to my history so it's easier to find things) & scan for doco you left..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directions you linked to state to create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ipv6.conf` containing some text which will instruct the system to never load the IPv6 kernel module.

To undo this, you simply remove the file, with `sudo`, and then reboot.

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ipv6.conf
sudo reboot   # Or reboot from the GUI, it doesn't matter how you reboot
```

Upon reboot, the kernel will be able to load the IPv6 modules, and you will then be able to configure (or autoconfigure) IPv6 on your system.