# Reinstallation of Ubuntu WSL 18.04 and Python3-pip installation issues

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, python3

I deleted and reinstalled Ubuntu by following the instructions  [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/261188/how-to-uninstall-or-reinstall-windows-10s-ubuntu-bash-shell/) but the same issues with pip installation persisted even after I've reinstalled Ubuntu. I suspect that the re-installation process did not totally help me remove Ubuntu.

Just to be clear that the Ubuntu I am installing is a bash shell and not a disk image that requires partitioning - just downloading a copy of Ubuntu from Windows Store would do in my case

How can I cleanly remove all of Ubuntu bash files on (Windows 10 Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763)?

The steps I took to reinstall are:

1. Uninstall Ubuntu under programs and features
2. Deselect Windows Subsystem of Linux from apps & features
3. Restart on clean reboot (as prompted by windows)
4. Reinstall Ubuntu on Windows Store
5. Setup
6. Run sudo apt-get update
7. Run pip installation

I've seen other methods of uninstalling such as `wslconfig.exe /u Ubuntu`, but I did the aforementioned way because of the Fall Creators update which allows this method. I'm not sure what's the difference between them and if it will make a difference in my case.

However, the same pip issues persisted, does this way of reinstalling guarantee that I get a fresh copy of python environment? What have I possibly done wrong?

The reason why I wanted to reinstall Ubuntu is because my pip is not functioning properly on only Ubuntu and not on Windows OS. The example is as follows: 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMDqV.png)

Any advise will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Further details about what other stuff I have tried to troubleshoot the pip installation

CACHING

Some recommended to use `--no-cache-dir` but it did not work and I even tried `rm -rf ./cache/pip` but that also did not work. So I reinstalled Ubuntu WSL, hoping that it will work but it didn't.

NETWORK ISSUE

`ping pypi.org` does not work and returns the following message and freezes
`PING pypi.python.org(2a04:4e42:2::223 (2a04:4e42:2::223)) 56 data bytes`

What I have done about this issue:

1.Tried disabling IPv6 as recommended by @Kulfy  here

Got the following error:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
```

2.Copied and pasted the following into Ubuntu:
Tried with sudo and root with the command below

sudo/root

```
cat >/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ipv6.conf <<EOF
# Turn of IPv6 by blacklisting the module.
# Even though it isn't needed.
blacklist ipv6

EOF
$
```

It returned the following `-bash: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ipv6.conf: Permission denied`

as recommended  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748636/issues-with-disabling-ipv6-on-ubuntu-14-0-4) but also did not work

3. Setting Preferences for IPv4 over IPv6

I have also set preferences for IPv4 by uncommenting these codes
and editing the file by doing

```
sudo vi /etc/gai.conf
```

and then... uncommenting

```
#For sites which prefer IPv4 connections change the last line to
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
...
#    For sites which use site-local IPv4 addresses behind NAT there is
#    the problem that even if IPv4 addresses are preferred they do not
#    have the same scope and are therefore not sorted first.  To change
#    this use only these rules:
#
scopev4 ::ffff:169.254.0.0/112  2
scopev4 ::ffff:127.0.0.0/104    2
scopev4 ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96       14
```

This is as recommended 
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958876/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

This still has not worked. So, it may not be an issue with IPv6

Comment: What issues did you face with pip?

Comment: The installation of pip modules took longer than usual. It get stuck at collecting [module name]... Some recommended to use the --no-cache-dir option but I used it to no avail. So I decided to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using some antivirus such as KasperSky or firewall?

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick replies！I currently have McAfee which expired and I tried uninstalling the antivirus as well and I have also disabled Windows defender while running Ubuntu. This issue also does not occur on my Windows. Have added to my original post an image for a more detailed version of my installation procedure

Comment: Are you able to run other commands such as `sudo apt update` successfully?

Comment: yep all the Ubuntu related installations are normal, but the moment when I try to install pip, the exact same issues like stated repeated itself, which puzzles me because I thought wiping out Ubuntu would have removed all python environments related to Ubuntu

Comment: Can you ping `pypi.python.org` from the venv?

Comment: It gets stuck like so: ping pypi.python.org --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PING pypi.python.org(2a04:4e42:2::223 (2a04:4e42:2::223)) 56 data bytes and doesn't return anything after that. But, ping 8.8.8.8 has no issues. If it helps, all my issues occured after I made a huge API call to yfinance, I don't know if this clue will help in your troubleshooting?

Comment: Try disabling IPv6.

Comment: Is there a way to know if Ubuntu is running IPv4 or IPv6? I tried to disable IPv6 by going on windows system properties and disabling IPv6 from there, but pinging and pip installing still does not work

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/484487/816190

Comment: I updated my original post, with what I've tried... Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/958876 is more specific for WSL.

Comment: I tried this: "sudo vi /etc/gai.conf". The changes were successfully made, however, running pip3 install [module name] still takes a long time like before.

Comment: I'm out of clue for now. This is surely not an issue with PIP. May be someone with more experience in WSL look into this.

Comment: We have come such a long way, I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Kulfy, I have come back with some more clues. I realised that I pinged 8.8.8.8 and there are packets returned. But, when I ping-ed google.com nothing returns. More research tells me that this could be a network issue. Also, on another laptop connected to the same wifi network, pip installation has no issues. If I provide ifconfig files on both laptops, would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What to check after reinstallation

In my case, I realised that even after re-installation, the issues persist. However, I realised that Hamachi's LogMeIn client was not in offline mode, which caused its Ethernet connection to interfere with Ubuntu's internet connection (but not on Windows OS). This is why when I pinged `google.com` it returned `PING google.com(2404:6800:4003:c03::8a (2404:6800:4003:c03::8a)) 56 data bytes` and stopped. The steps that @Kulfy took to help troubleshoot pointed me in the right direction, which made me realise that there was an additional Ethernet connection running.

In the future, if anyone still faces issue with their internet connection, even after reinstalling, please check that you do not have any antivirus software or other servers running at the same time, which may interfere with your Ubuntu's internet connection.

Go to ***Control Panel→Network and Internet→Network Connections*** on Windows to check whether you have additional servers running. Disable them (if found) and retry.

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiousity, did you got `PING pypi.python.org(2a04:4e42:2::223 (2a04:4e42:2::223)) 56 data bytes` while pinging **`google.com`**? Seems little unconsistency.

Comment: Hi Kulfy, thanks for the reminder. To answer, your question, yes, when I pinged ```pypi.python.org``` I got ```PING pypi.python.org(2a04:4e42:2::223 (2a04:4e42:2::223)) 56 data bytes``` . This happens every time the LogMeIn Hamachi server is online, which activated the Ethernet connection. Why is that inconsistent, in your opinion? This only happens with Ubuntu and does not happen with Windows OS command prompt, I'm not sure why that is so?

Comment: It seems you didn't read my comment carefully. I wonder why you got `PING` **`pypi.python.org`** while pinging **`google.com`** since you mentioned in the answer: *when I pinged `google.com` it returned `PING pypi.python.org(2a04:4e42:2::223 (2a04:4e42:2::223)) 56 data bytes` and stopped*. But you mentioned you got `PING` **`pypi.python.org`** while pinging **`pypi.python.org`**. Did you mistype things in the answer?

Comment: yes, I missed that out, will correct the post for clarification. The correct answer should be ```PING google.com(2404:6800:4003:c03::8a (2404:6800:4003:c03::8a)) 56 data bytes``` when google.com is pinged