# Port is not open

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, netstat

This is could be a database issue but to check if related to network configuration.

To start DB i USE :

```
Running rethinkdb 2.3.4~0trusty (GCC 4.8.2)...
Running on Linux 3.19.0-39-generic x86_64
Loading data from directory /root/rethinkdb_data
warn: Cache size is very low and may impact performance.
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080
```

Can the see the output states that 'Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080'

But when I attempt to connect to this port using server IP address over http the request times out. So it appears the port is not open,

I run `netstat -tuplen` and receive :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
    tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          871572      21433/rethinkdb
```

local address of `0 :::8080` should be `127.0.0.1:::8080` or `localhost:::8080` ?

Are there other command I can try to diagnose this issue ?

Comment: That's a TCPv6 socket. You don't use IPv4 addresses like `127.0.0.1` with that. `::` means it accepts connections from any network interface. `::1` means it accepts connections only over the loopback interface (so, `localhost`).

Comment: @Olathe '::1' should be ':::' as ::1 is not in netstat output ? When check ip address on machine it is in ip4 format : 12.23.34.21 , so how can I connect to it ?

Comment: What `bind` option(s) do you have in the conf file? it looks like at one point there was an issue with `bind=all` only binding to IPv6 addresses - see [bind=all does not bind to IPv4 addresses](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1897)

Comment: @Olathe please see question update

Comment: @steeldriver please see question update

Comment: It would be good if you posted the resolution as an answer instead of editing it into your question - that way it will help others who have the same issue. Also you will be able to accept your own answer and gain rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments below were a big help. After reading https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1897 I tried disable ipv6 by following :

[How to disable IPv6 in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04)

This did not seem to have an impact.

Last comment of : https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1897

> "Hi, @danielmewes yes you are right, my problem was iptables, i dont
>   know why, but this time was iptables blocked the 8080. Last month i
>   installer another rethinkdb cluster on centos 7 minimal install and I
>   didn't had any trouble with iptables, but this time i had. Probably
>   because last install configure the firewall exception and this new
>   version don't.
>
> Thank for your response.
>
> Sergio"

This appears to have been my issue also as unblocking the port 8080 allowed me to connect to admin UI on port 8080. Command to unblock port 8080 with iptables :

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

and start server : `rethinkdb --bind all`