# Failed to install youtube-dl

Tags: software-installation, internet, youtube

I"m tryting to do `sudo apt install youtube-dl` but im getting the below error during installation.

```
 E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tbb/libtbb2_4.4~20151115-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

also, as per suggestion  i do `apt-get update --fix-missing`  but not helping much

Comment: is it your internet? try rebooting

Comment: @MarkYisri system reboot is not helping, i tried that .

Comment: Interestingly, I can access that URL from my browser. Try downloading the file and manually installing with `sudo dpkg -i <path to file>`

Comment: It looks like a temporary problem on your DNS, change your mirror if it persist, but youtube-dl often needs fast updates, I'd suggest installing it from here: https://youtube-dl.org/

Comment: Your problem *is* with the internet connection and nothing to do with what you're installing. It can be temporary (that's the message you should have read) or it can be blocked anywhere from a local proxy to the ISP itself. You can try changing the server.

Comment: @artyom Seems you have got it right. I often face 'server not found' while browsing.  Can you suggest how to get rid of this.

Comment: @EetSandhu Just change your mirror, take a look at this; https://askubuntu.com/questions/37753/how-can-i-get-apt-to-use-a-mirror-close-to-me-or-choose-a-faster-mirror

Comment: @Artyom I did as suggest in the linked post but to no avail :( . I even have an active question regarding dns change here http://askubuntu.com/questions/856230/unable-to-downlaod-anything-check-internet-connection-even-firefox-not-workin

Comment: @EetSandhu No harm trying to disable ipv6, maybe something is wrong with your ipv6 setup, disable it as seen here; https://askubuntu.com/a/768022/602695

Comment: @Artyom i've disabled ipv6 for firefox browser. I don't see any improvement as far as 'Server not found' occurrence is concerned. A bill payment takes at least 3 attempts. this is not the case with my desktop using windows 7 :( . Seems like there's seriously something wrong my my ubuntu copy. I'm using Ubuntu Mate on a lenovo laptop.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler way. Uninstall current `youtube-dl`(optional) by running

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
```

Install latest `youtube-dl` by running the following commands:

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

[source](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)

Comment: Why uninstall if it wasn't installed?

Comment: @CelticWarrior, just precaution, It can be skipped.