# Installing gparted on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gparted

How do I install gparted on Ubuntu 18.04? Every method proves to return the same unsuccessful result.

1) Through the terminal.

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
  libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libsigc++-2.0-0v5
Suggested packages:
  xfsprogs reiserfsprogs reiser4progs jfsutils kpartx dmraid gpart
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gparted libatkmm-1.6-1v5 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 libglibmm-2.4-1v5
  libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 libsigc++-2.0-0v5
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 126 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,798 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 amd64 2.10.0-2
  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 amd64 2.56.0-1
  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libatkmm-1.6-1v5 amd64 2.24.2-3
  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libcairomm-1.0-1v5 amd64 1.12.2-3
  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpangomm-1.4-1v5 amd64 2.40.1-4
  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 amd64 1:2.24.5-2
  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 gparted amd64 0.30.0-3ubuntu1
  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsigc++-2.0/libsigc++-2.0-0v5_2.10.0-2_amd64.deb  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibmm2.4/libglibmm-2.4-1v5_2.56.0-1_amd64.deb  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/atkmm1.6/libatkmm-1.6-1v5_2.24.2-3_amd64.deb  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cairomm/libcairomm-1.0-1v5_1.12.2-3_amd64.deb  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pangomm/libpangomm-1.4-1v5_2.40.1-4_amd64.deb  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtkmm2.4/libgtkmm-2.4-1v5_2.24.5-2_amd64.deb  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gparted/gparted_0.30.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
```

2) Through Ubuntu Software Center

[image]

3) Downloading the .deb.

[image]

Any idea on how do I rectify this and go ahead with the installation?

Comment: `Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 amd64 2.10.0-2
  502  Connection timed out [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]` - you're trying to fetch the files via IPv6. Are you sure that is what you want? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 9):

Open your terminal and write the following commands

1. `sudo apt-get update` - 
   to update the repositories and package
2. `sudo apt-get install gparted` - install gparted
3. `sudo dpkg -l gparted` - check and confirm installation
4. `sudo gparted`  - to open gparted

and you are done :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Download Gparted as an ISO file
2. Burn it in a USB flash
3. Plug the USB flash into your Computer
4. Start your computer with the bootable USB that you already made
5. Use the Gparted app like live

*And good luck*