# Trying to install GParted but error showing up

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to install GParted, but the following error message shows:

```
E: http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libsigc++-2.0-0v5 amd64 2.10.0-2 is not (yet) available (Could not resolve 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com')
```

[image]

Could someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: What command did you use? Maybe try this (2nd answer) : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053670/installing-gparted-on-ubuntu-18-04/1094011

Comment: if you can't resolve your issue, you can still use `gparted-live` as a bootable CD or USB.

Comment: The Message `Could not resolve 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'` means, there is a network related error. But it is hard to say why the name could not be resolved without knowing the setup. At this point I would ask: Is the network cable connected?

Comment: @Célestin Taramarcaz I tried through the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: @LupusE I am using a laptop without an Ethernet port but it is connected to Wi-Fi.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the Ubuntu Software Center as your first option. Please check your network connection and give us the the error message you get when entering these commands in a terminal :
1.  `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install gparted`