# Unknown hostname is attacking my server?

Tags: networking, server, security

It seems to be someone is trying to attack me from unknown hostnames.

How can determine the IP address of these kind of hostnames, since they do not respond to ping?

Is there a way to block these "hidden ip" connections?

```
tcp6       0      0 removed:http      chubao.quirkydesi:30267 TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 removed:http      chubao.quirkydesi:29819 TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 removed:http      chubao.quirkydesi:27674 TIME_WAIT
```

My `netstat` is full of these.

[netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhIh.png)

Comment: If the attacker is any good they will spoof their ip or use a large public ip or other techniques so you may be wasting your time trying to track them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing your logs, it seems like your computer is being access using IPv6 only.

The simple solution (assuming that you are using IPv4 only) - will be: **Disable IPv6**

[How to disable ipv6 in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/484487/544264)