# I am unable to update ubuntu 14.10 using sudo apt-get update

Tags: updates, 14.10

I tried to update after I could not browse on my mozilla browser.  I can ping out so I am on the network.  DNS does not resolve using the ip address.  The following is my output from trying apt-get update.

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease

Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to ca.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19 80]
Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease

Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80 (2607:f8b0:400a:804::1007). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2607:f8b0:400a:804::1007 80]
Reading package lists...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I cannot use apt-get update](http://askubuntu.com/questions/336870/i-cannot-use-apt-get-update)

Comment: are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: can you get to http://security.ubuntu.com your system may not be configured to use ipv6

Comment: @DigitalChemist what do you mean by "DNS does not resolve using the ip address" ? can you ping www.google.com in terminal ?