# airmon-ng with internal wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, vmware, backtrack

hello i'm using backtrack 5 using vmware 10 workstation .when i type `airmon-ng` it doesn't shows anything .

[image]

but when i type `ifconfig` i got following output .

[image]

this is my internal wifi card[divice manager].

[image]

how ever i have made following network settings

[image]

i searched a lot and found lot of answers but still didn't get a clear answer ..

my question is if i have only internal wifi adapter [not external usb adapter] ,can't i use it ??

and is there any way to use internal device with backtrack...i have see that "airmon not support your internal device" some where on internet ..so is there internel wifi devices which doesn't work with backtrack -airmon at all ?? thanks

Comment: Backtrack is off-topic here. Please ask on [unix.se].

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/178804/wireless-network-in-virtualbox Especially: "There is no wireless connection inside the virtualbox environment. All "virtual" connections are in reference to cable/wired connected ones. So when you enable a Network card in your virtual guest, it is a virtual wired connection you are creating not a virtual wireless one."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: This forum is about Ubuntu. Questions about other Linux distributions such as BackTrack should be posted on Unix&Linux StackExchange forum. Anyway, BackTrack is old and deprecated. Use Kali Linux instead of it!

But although I can provide you some help here. The ifconfig does not show any wireless device! It only shows **eth0** which is a wired connection and **lo** which is the local loopback interface. Therefore you also can not detect any devices with aircrack. As you run BackTrack inside a VM, I think the problem is how your VirtualBox(?) bridges the physical wifi adapter to your VM.
But unfortunately I don't know about how this would get virtualized, so giving you this hint is all I can do.
I hope it helped you anyway. Greetings!

Comment: Next time, flag the question as "Offtopic" - it does not help to have a post answering this if the post itself is going to get nuked as a result of "offtopic"

Comment: @ThomasW. I answered this because Ubuntu would exactly behave in the same way. I have both Kali and Ubuntu and run the aircack suite on both of them.

Comment: @ByteCommander tnx i will ask in unix site .this is also helped

Comment: No problem, I'm here to help wherever I can! :)

Comment: @ByteCommander if i install backtrack as live not virtual ,will it detect internal wifi device ??

Comment: Yes, of course! There is no difference afaik between a live and an installed system concerning the hardware access. It will only discard any changes (except if you mount a hard disk partition or USB device to save some files on it) unless you create a persistent live system.