# Ubuntu 17.10 no wi-fi adapter found

Tags: wireless, 17.10

I use msi GE62-7rd laptop, intel dual band wireless-ac 3168 and Ubuntu using virtualbox.

but couldn't find wifi signal

and enter command `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
couldn't find network controller

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to check virtualbox documentation about guest OS access to PCI wireless devices

Comment: please, I want detail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless Network in Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178804/wireless-network-in-virtualbox)