# Killer Bluetooth and wifi not working with Bionic Beaver 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualbox, bluetooth

Could use some help here.  I am running Bionic Beaver 18.04 in VirtualBox before I do a full install on my laptop....
I can't seem to get the bluetooth or wifi to work?
I have tried the below to no avail.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1174624

Killer manuf site says it uses the ath10k driver....but doesn't seem to work or recognize it
https://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads/kb/faq/1-killer-1535-1525-1435-in-ubuntu-debian

I have tried the lsusb and it recognizes my ethernet port but that's it.
Any ideas?

Comment: You can't test Wifi on Virtualbox.

Comment: Well, now I feel like an idiot - how do I do this running ubuntu?

Comment: Boot from LiveUSB and test. `ath10k` should work without any issues. Boot from the installer and select "Try Ubuntu".

Comment: Post results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`  Killer Networking has started using Intel Chipsets rather than Atheros

Comment: Why don't you edit the question to include results from the terminal that I requested from a Live ISO?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wireless Network in Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178804/wireless-network-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old post but I'm struggling with this network card (1435) too and can only advise people with the same card to change it if possible. It has very bad performances on Linux. The driver can be found at https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware in the QCA6174 folder. There are many firmwares to try out. I could not find one that doesn't crash or has good performance uploading files. The upload with this card is really slow. Really slow!

To load the module in the command line I have to:

```
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
sudo modprobe ath10k_core
```

Although this is not an ideal solution, this will load the driver. I thought it might be helpful to someone having problems with this network card.

Comment: This is not a thread, and your post is not an answer.