# Share a folder between Windows 8.1 guest and Ubuntu 14.04 host in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, windows, virtualbox, samba, sharing

I have a computer running Ubuntu 14.04, with Windows 8.1 running inside VirtualBox. I needed Windows for a number of reasons, mainly for Office and OneDrive (school things).

My problem is that I can't seem to create a shared folder between the two computers. I have a folder `/home/graham/Windows`, that I have set as a shared folder for the guest in VirtualBox.

**Edit:** In regards to other documentation, most is for Windows has a host and Ubuntu as a guest, or an older version of Windows as a guest. Everything I find says the shared folder should just appear within Windows 8.1, but this is not the case.

When trying to mount `\\vboxsvr\Windows` within Windows 8.1, it says that the

> server can't be accessed.

I have virtualbox guest addons installed on the guest.

Here is a screenshot of the error given by windows when trying to map the network drive:

[image: Network Error]

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Graham

Answer (score 5):

I normally go into Virtual Box setting for the VM in questions, select the folder to share and set the display name I want, and select permanent and auto-mount in the dialog box. Start the virtual machine and Windows should display your shared folders from the host OS as drive letters just like a mounted network share.

This only works if you have guest tools installed on guest OS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't get an option for permanent in the dialogue box. I can specify the path of the folder, the display name, set it as read-only (which I don't), and set auto mount. I get the same error in windows as before. And I do have the guest tools installed.

Comment: @grahamhoyes can you add a screenshot of the error [to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/468862/edit)

Comment: @grahamhoyes , you are logged in as graham/have read write permission for the folder your trying to mount right?

Comment: @Xubu-Tur I linked the screenshot on imgur, apparently I can't upload photos here yet.

Comment: @user3623501 I am logged in as graham on the host computer yes, and that account has read / write permissions for the folder. Do I need to specify them for the guest OS? And if so, how?

Comment: @user3623501 You should try this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/81757/sharing-between-host-and-guest-in-virtualbox/81816#81816